# Symmetric Curve

Tags: differential-geometry

I am having hard time solving the following question:

> Let $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ curve in natural parameterization.
>
> Suppose the curve has curvature $\kappa(s)=3s^2$
>
> Then prove that $\gamma$ has symmetric axis, and that that $|\gamma|$ is bounded.

I tried using Frenet base to argue that :

> $\ddot{\gamma}$ = $-3s^2$$\hat{n}$
>
> $\dot{\hat{n}}$ = $3s^2$$\dot{\gamma}$

But got stuck, I tried to first prove the bound since I had know idea how to approach the symmetry question. When i tried to go for the integration I used Frenet base , only to fail and get the followung result:
$ 1 \geq \dot{x} = \int{\ddot{x}} =_{_{Frenet}} \int{3s^2\dot{y}} = s^3\dot{y} - \int{3s^2\ddot{y}}$

Then I tried:
$x = \int \dot{x} $

But it didn't help me.

I remember from my ODE course something about antisymetric ODE's , but I don't think I am actually allowed to use it (even if I did , I already forgot it)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @sinbadh think that the second part Of the question means that it is not a closed interval (elseways it would be too simple). I updated the brief

Comment: If you suppose $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$, then $$\gamma(s)=(\int_{-\infty}^s\cos(t^3+c_1)dt,\int_{-\infty}^s\sin(t^3+c_1)dt)+C_2$$, where $c_1\in\mathbb{R}$ and $C_2\in\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @sinbadh I can see why this is a solution, but I can't see why this is the only solution (for example, if we apply any positive isometry on your solution, then we get another solution)

Comment: I'm applying the Fundamental Theorem of existence and uniqueness of curves in the space: given two continuous functions  $\kappa$ and $\tau$, there is only  a curve $\gamma$ whose curvature and torsion are $\kappa$ and $\tau$. Uniqueness is in the sense of rigid motions.

Comment: So, EVERY curve $\gamma$ with $\kappa=3s^2$ and $\tau=0$ is of this form. Indeed, if you change $c_1$, then you are rotating the curve. If you change $C_2$, you are translating the curve. So, if the aseverations are true for $c_1=0$ and $C_2=(0,0)$, then they are true for every curve with $\kappa=3s^2$ and $\tau=0$ (since both aseverations are invariants under rigid motions in the plane)

Comment: @sinbadh I found my mistake (I forgot another approach I had in mind)

I can see why this is symmetric. I can see why this is bounded. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit for @sindabah.
If we write $\nu(t) = \dot{\gamma}(t) = (\cos(\alpha(t)),\sin(\alpha(t)))$ , and apply Frenet equations we get:

> -$\dot{\alpha}(t)sin(\alpha(t)) =-3t^2\sin(\alpha(t))$
>
> $\dot{\alpha}(t)cos(\alpha(t)) =-3t^2\cos(\alpha(t))$

So $\alpha(t) = t^3 +const.$ .

Using the fact that given $\kappa$ , there is a unique curve with curvature $\kappa{(t)}$ (up to isometry and reparametrization)

So $\gamma{(t)}= (\int_{-∞}^{t}\cos(t^3+c_1)dt,∫_{-\infty}^{t}\sin(t^3+c_1)dt)+C‌_2$ where $c_1,C_2$ are constants.

W.l.o.g. assume $c_1=C_2=0$ , it is not hard to see that this function has symmetry axis and that it is bounded.